# How do I differentiate an empty model from an initial model in an ASP.NET MVC 4 controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, get, data-annotations, model-binding

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I'm trying to implement the following concept:

- Browsing `http://.../PersonData/Show?id=A5668A31-9AAC-4A14-B471-7C9BA236961D` should display the data of the person identified by the given ID.
- Browsing `http://.../PersonData/Show` should display a view with a form where I can input an ID into a text box. When I submit the form, the browser should navigate, but not post, to the URL given above (i.e., the form's method is set to GET).
- When I submit the form without entering an ID (causing the URL `http://.../PersonData/Show?id=` to be browsed), ASP.NET MVC model validation should display a message that the ID is required. (With or without JavaScript being enabled.)

To implement this, I build a model like this:

```
class Model
{
  [Required]
  public Guid? Id { get; set; }
}
```

And now I have the problem that when browsing `http://.../PersonData/Show` for the first time, ASP.NET model validation immediately gives an error that the ID is required because it does not distinguish between the case where the form was submitted without an ID (`?id=`) and the case where the action was invoked for the first time (id is not given at all).

Ideas I've had:

- Use two different controller actions and URLs (like `http://.../PersonData/Search` and `http://.../PersonData/Show?id=`) to differentiate between first browsing and empty form submission.
- Use an additional form parameter (like `http://.../PersonData/Show` and `http://.../PersonData/Show?valueGiven=true&id=`).
- Inspect the URL parameters from the action method using the `Request` object and clear `ModelState` errors for `"id"` if that key was not present in the URL.

What is the best/suggested way of solving this? Is there a better fourth approach?

(One thing that didn't work was to add two action methods with the same name for GET actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public void Show() { /* return view with initial browsing logic */ }
[HttpGet]
public void Show(Model model) { /* return view with subsequent browsing logic */ }
```

This seems not to be allowed by ASP.NET MVC.)

**Update 2013-06-25:** Sorry, there were two mistake in my sample, the ID should have been a `Guid`, not a string; and of course, I'm binding the Model in my action method because I need the `Required` attribute to be evaluated.

And this is my routing configuration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes (RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute ("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute (
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you show the route config? Looks like the ID in the route is not setted as optional!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am going to have both methods as GET, then I prefer your first approach: A search page and a results page with parameters passed in. This is the approach I like to take if I want the user to share links, since all parameters will be in the querystring.

If on the other hand, sharing is not really an issue, I like to have a GET method to display the form, which will then be submitted to the POST version of the action method with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

if you do not pass id, then id will be null.  If you pass id with a value, id will be "" (ie, the empty string.. String.Empty)

As such, you cannot use the Required attribute, as this will generate an error.  You will have to check the value manually in your controller.

A better approach would be to create a special route to handle the version with id, using a route constraint.  The id in this route would not be optional, but the constraint would prevent routes that don't have the id at all to not be selected.

I don't have the ability to create and test this case for you right now, but that should give you something to go on.  Perhaps someone else can whip something up.

Information on Route Constraints can be found here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Comment: Thanks, you are right, using a string (and omitting the Required attribute) I could manually check. However, I made a mistake in my original question text and actually have a `Guid?` - in this case, there is no distinguishing third value (the model binder binds both "empty" cases to `null`). Omitting the `RequiredAttribute` means I also have to manually attach client-side validation, so it's unfortunate (but of course possible).

Comment: About the route constraint: `id` is passed as a URL parameter (because it's an HTML form with GET method). I cannot create a route based on an that, can I? And if so, how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if case to your initial show function

```
[HttpGet]
public void Show(int? id) {

    if(id.HasValue) {
     /* return view with subsequent browsing logic */ 
    }
    else {
      /* return view with initial browsing logic */
    }
}
```

EDIT:
This may work

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class RequestMatchAnyAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
    {
        public string MatchFormKey { get; set; }

        public RequestMatchAnyAttribute(string matchAnyFormKeys)
        {
            this.MatchFormKey = matchAnyFormKeys;
        }

        public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[MatchFormKey] != null;
        }
    }


[HttpGet]
public void Show() {
    /* default view */
}

[ActionName("Show")]
[RequestMatchAny("Id")]
[HttpGet]
public void ShowEdit(int? id) {

    if(id.HasValue) {
     /* return edit view */ 
    }
    else {
      /* return create view */
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I need - I need to differentiate three cases: initial brwosing, subsequent browsing with id given, and subsequent browsing with no id given. (Note that there were two mistakes in my original question text.)

Comment: @FabianSchmied Why not use a different action for the list and one for the create/edit

Comment: Sure, that's the first option in my question :)
I just wanted to see if there are better alternatives.